# Non-blocking download using curl in R

Tags: r, curl

I am writing some code where I download many pages of from a web API, do some processing, and combine them into a data frame.  The API takes ~30 seconds to respond to each request, so it would be convenient to send the request for the next page while doing the processing for the current page.  I can do this using, e.g., `mcparallel`, but that seems like overkill.  The `curl` package claims that it can make non-blocking connections, but this does not seem to work for me.

From `vignette("intro", "curl")`:

> As of version 2.3 it is also possible to open connetions in
>   non-blocking mode. In this case readBin and readLines will return
>   immediately with data that is available without waiting. For
>   non-blocking connections we use isIncomplete to check if the download
>   has completed yet.
>
> ```
> con <- curl("https://httpbin.org/drip?duration=1&numbytes=50")
> open(con, "rb", blocking = FALSE) 
> while(isIncomplete(con)){  
>  buf <- readBin(con, raw(), 1024)
>  if(length(buf)) 
>   cat("received: ", rawToChar(buf), "\n")
> }
> close(con)
> ```

The expected result is that the `open` should return immediately, and then 50 asterisks should be progressively printed over 1 second as the results come in.  For me, the `open` blocks for about a second, and then the asterisks are printed all at once.

Is there something else I need to do? Does this work for anyone else?

I am using R version 3.3.2, curl package version 3.1, and libcurl3 version 7.47.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I have tried in RStudio and the command line R console, with the same results.

Comment: `?curl_fetch_multi`

Comment: OK, it seems like that works for me.  If you write it up as an answer I'll accept it.